# Wordpress category subscription plugin sending multiple emails

Tags: wordpress, email, subscriptions

I am using the Categories Subscription plugin on a Wordpress site.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-subscriptions/
Using Wordpress version 3.3.1

My client is reporting multiple emails being sent.  Some users are receiving multiple emails,  other are receiving the expect amount.

There is no obvious difference between the users.  Some users are subscribe to more categories than others, some roles are restricted access to certain categories.  However there is no consistency between the user attributes (category access / subscription) and the number of emails being sent (i.e. one administrator with the same access/subscription setup as another administrator receives only one email, the other receives multiple emails).

Has anyone come across this problem?

Thanks in advance
Dave

Comment: Have you raised this in the plugin's support section?

Comment: I hadn't (not had much luck getting support on the wp site in the past to be honest).. but I have now.  Thanks